# Assign a variable a value if a checkbox is clicked within a form javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to assign a variable a value as long as certain checkboxes are clicked. The code below works for what I need, but as soon as I sit it within a form, it breaks the function.

I think I'm missing something pretty simple, but for the life of me can't find out how to select a form value - also would anyone have advice on how to scale this for use with several checkboxes?

```js
function cb3(checkbox) {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    alert("function called!");
    $userChoice1 = 'value1';
  } else {
    $userChoice1 = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb3test" name="cb3" value="value1" onClick="cb3(this)">Value1
```

Thanks in advance, applogies if this is a duplicate, although I couldn't find a question with regards to forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$('#cb3test').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           alert("function called!");
            $userChoice1 = 'value1';
        } else {
           $userChoice1 = '';
        }
    });
```

Comment: but he can use as he has included jquery.min.js

Comment: The jquery was added by @Daniel in the last edit and it shouldn't .. (Rolled back).

Answer (score 0):

So, you could have several checkboxes inside a form, and then use a the onsubmit event to check the values of all checkbox inputs:

```
<form id="myId" name="myForm" onsubmit="myFunction()">
   <input type="checkbox" id="cb3test" name="cb3" value="value1"/>
   <input type="checkbox" id="cb3test" name="cb4" value="value2"/>
   <input type="submit"/>
</form>

myFunction() {
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
        {your logic here} 
    }  
}
}
```

PS: I don't know if you can run this exact code, as it's been long since I last coded html/js, but I think you can get the idea.